# while loop not stopping when I pass it a false statement referencing a string

Tags: javascript, string, function

I want the user to pick a number from 1 - 10 and then decide to if they want to sum or multiply 1...n.

I'm able to debug for when the user puts in something other than a number from 1 - 10 using a while loop.

But when I do the same thing with a string value, it doesn't stop the while loop.

What's going on here?

```
let pickNumber = prompt("pick a number from 1 - 10");
let sumTotal = 0;
let multiplyTotal = 1;

while(pickNumber < 1 || pickNumber > 10) {
    pickNumber = prompt("pick a number from 1 - 10");
}

let pickFunction = prompt("sum or multiply?")

while(pickFunction !== "sum" || pickFunction !== "multiply") {
    pickFunction = prompt('entry not recognized, try again. Choose sum or multiply')
}


switch (pickFunction) {
    case "sum": 
        sum();
        break;
    case "multiply":
        multiply()
        break;
    default:
        pickFunction = prompt('entry not recognized, try again. Choose sum or multiply')
}

function sum() {
    for (i = 1; i <= pickNumber; i++) {
        sumTotal += i;
        console.log(sumTotal)
    }
}

function multiply() {
    for (i = 1; i <= pickNumber; i++) {
        multiplyTotal *= i;
        console.log(multiplyTotal)
    }
}
```

Comment: if `pickFunction` is equal to "sum", then it's not equal to "multiply", and vice-versa.

Comment: You probably want `&&` instead of `||` for the second `while` loop. It's a logic error. "If thing is not A or thing is not B" will always be true, no matter what "thing" is .

Comment: `while(pickFunction !== "sum" || pickFunction !== "multiply") {` that is a no no. It will never exit that while block because you never set pickFunction inside the loop.

Also, your first while loop is only testing numbers, and not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop will run indefinitely - you need to change OR `||` to AND `&&`:

```
while(pickFunction !== "sum" && pickFunction !== "multiply")
```

Also ensure you're multiplying numbers and numbers, not strings and numbers:

```
let pickNumber = parseInt(prompt("pick a number from 1 - 10"));
while (pickNumber < 1 || pickNumber > 10) {
    pickNumber = parseInt(prompt("pick a number from 1 - 10"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the && worked. Got a little confused because of the !==

Comment: Thanks for the added parseInt() too, forgot about that method.